# My Pagination is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

After clicking the buttons my pagination is not working !! Anyone please look into it

Controller class

```
        public class DataTableEditRemoveController {
    public List<Account> accs { get; set; }
            //used to get a hold of the account record selected for deletion
            public string SelectedAccountId { get; set; }
            Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
            Public Integer size{get;set;}
            public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
                get{
                    if(setCon == null){
                        size = 10;
                        string queryString = 'Select id, name, phone, website, Active__c from Account';
                        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
                        setCon.setPageSize(size);
                        noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
                    }
                    return setCon;
                }set;
            }
            Public List<Account> getAccounts(){
                List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
                for(Account a : (List<Account>)setCon.getRecords())
                    accList.add(a);
                return accList;
            }
            public pageReference refresh() {
                setCon = null;
                getAccounts();
                setCon.setPageNumber(1);
                return null;
            }
            public DataTableEditRemoveController() {
               //load account data into our DataTable
               LoadData();
            }
            private void LoadData() {
               accs = [Select id, name, phone, website, Active__c from Account];
            }   

            public void DeleteAccount(){
                // if for any reason we are missing the reference 
                if (SelectedAccountId == null) {
                    return;
                }
                // find the account record within the collection
                Account tobeDeleted = null;
                for(Account a : accs)
                if (a.Id == SelectedAccountId) {
                    tobeDeleted = a;
                    break;
               }    
                //if account record found delete it
                if (tobeDeleted != null) {
                Delete tobeDeleted;
                }
                //refresh the data
                LoadData();
           }

        }
```

Visual Force Page

```
<apex:page controller="DataTableEditRemoveController" sidebar="false">
<apex:form id="form" >
<apex:pageBlock title="Accounts">
    <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="row">
            <apex:column >
            <!-- Editing a Record(In Salesforce for standard objects you can follow this 
                            format to get the URL for their edit page: /{RecordId}/e)
                            /{RecordId}/e?retURL={returnURL} -->   
                <apex:outputLink title="" value="/{!row.id}/e?retURL=/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}" style="font-weight:bold">Edit</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) DeleteAccount('{!row.Id}');" style="font-weight:bold">Del</a>

            </apex:column>
            <!-- List of Records --> 
            <apex:column value="{!row.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!row.Phone}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!row.Website}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!row.Active__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:panelGrid columns="7">
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="First" action="{!setCon.first}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="Previous" action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="Next" action="{!setCon.next}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="Last" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>
                <apex:outputText >{!(setCon.pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((setCon.pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(setCon.pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="Refresh" action="{!refresh}" title="Refresh Page"/>
                <apex:outputPanel style="color:#4AA02C;font-weight:bold">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" startText="Fetching..." stopText=""/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:panelGrid>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!DeleteAccount}" name="DeleteAccount" reRender="form" >
   <!-- Deleting a Record --(param" tag to the actionFunction component which 
                            passes the Account ID to the controller and as soon as user 
                            clicks on the link.)--> 
    <apex:param name="accountid" value="" assignTo="{!SelectedAccountId}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find out following useful link with proper example and code :

[http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/01/pagination-using-apex-in-salesforce.html][1]

Comment: I also have lots of references but I dont know what is the problem with my code